# NCO : Masking netcdf file using another netcdf mask file with (0 - 1) values

Tags: netcdf, nco, data-masking

I have two .nc files `data.nc` and `mask.nc`.
Where: `data.nc` contain a variable called `temp` unmasked, while `mask.nc` contain the mask within a variable called `tmask` with `(0 - 1)` values.
Using `NCO`, how can I apply the masking for the `data.nc` file, such that zero mask values are set to missing, and unity mask values are retained unchanged?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you wish to do with the mask. Here is a common procedure, use the mask to replace the actual values with missing values:

```
ncks -A -v tmask mask.nc data.nc
ncap2 -s 'where(tmask == 0) temp=temp.get_miss()' data.nc out.nc
```

Documentation for `where` and `get_miss` is in the [manual](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2).

If `temp` has more records than `tmask` then make the `where()` condition operate on a copy of `tmask` that has been broadcast to the size of `temp`:

```
ncap2 -s '*big_mask=0*temp+tmask;where(big_mask == 0) temp=temp.get_miss()' data.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Thanks, it works successfully. However, masking is being applied only on the first time step of the variable `temp` .  To clarify, the `mask.nc` has only one timestep, while the `data.nc` has multi time-steps . So, how can I apply the masking for the whole time-steps of the `temp` variable in `data.nc`

Comment: As the manual explains, where() only operates on a hyperslab of the same size as the variable in the condition statement. So you first need to broadcase tmask to be the same size as temp. Clarified above.

Answer (score 1):

To do the same operation in `cdo` you could try this, which sets zero to missing in the mask first before taking the product:

```
cdo setctomiss,0 mask.nc maskm.nc
cdo mul data.nc maskm.nc masked_data.nc
```

`cdo` automatically repeats the mask to make it the same length in time as the data file, known as data "broadcasting".

I have a youtube video on [masking here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0nUE6mkINg) for further guidance, and other material on temporal [broadcasting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59puhuSnLnY).